# C++ ring buffer using some C++ 17 and coming C++ 20 std::span

Tags: c++, collections, c++17, circular-list, constant-expression

When I heard about the new Linux I/O interface `io_uring` I searched about the ring buffer.

I then thought I may replace my safe queue which is base on C++ 11 `std::queue` with a ring buffer to avoid repeated memory allocation during producing and consuming the packets between threads.

So I wanted to implement it as an exercise and started to look for some C++ implementations and found Boost's circular buffer.

I didn't look at its source code much but looked at the functionality it provides and tried to implement most of them but I still lack some.

So here is what I came up with:

```
#pragma once
#include <utility>
#include <optional>
#include "span.h"
#include <memory>

#define PROVIDE_CONTAINER_TYPES(T) \
    using value_type = T;\
    using pointer = T * ;\
    using const_pointer = const T *;\
    using reference = T & ;\
    using const_reference = const T &; \
    using size_type = std::size_t; \
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t

struct no_init_t {};
constexpr no_init_t no_init;

class ring_buffer_index
    {
        size_t index;

    public:

        ring_buffer_index() : index{0} {}

        ring_buffer_index(size_t pos) : index{pos} {}

        ring_buffer_index& operator++()
        {
            ++index;
            return *this;
        }

        ring_buffer_index& operator--()
        {
            --index;
            return *this;
        }

        ring_buffer_index operator+(size_t pos) const { return ring_buffer_index{index + pos}; }

        size_t operator-(ring_buffer_index other) const { return index - other.index; }

        bool operator==(ring_buffer_index other) const { return index == other.index; }

        bool operator!=(ring_buffer_index other) const { return index != other.index; }

        void operator+=(size_t times) { index += times; }

        void operator-=(size_t times) { index -= times; }

        void reset() { index = 0; }

        size_t as_index(size_t N) const
        {
            size_t pos = index;
            pos %= N;
            return pos;
        }

    };

    template <class T>
    class uninitialized_array
    {
        std::unique_ptr<unsigned char> raw_buffer;

    public:

        uninitialized_array() noexcept = default;

        uninitialized_array(size_t N) : raw_buffer{ new unsigned char[sizeof(T) * N] } {}

        uninitialized_array(uninitialized_array&& other) noexcept = default;

        uninitialized_array& operator=(uninitialized_array&& other) noexcept = default;

        void copy(const uninitialized_array& other, size_t N)
        {
            raw_buffer.reset();
            if (other.raw_buffer && N)
            {
                raw_buffer.reset(new unsigned char[sizeof(T) * N]);
                std::uninitialized_copy(other.ptr(), other.ptr() + N, ptr());
            }
        }

        void resize(size_t N)
        {
            raw_buffer.reset( new unsigned char[sizeof(T) * N] );
        }

        T * ptr() noexcept { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(raw_buffer.get()); }

        const T * ptr() const noexcept { return reinterpret_cast<const T*>(raw_buffer.get()); }

        T& operator[](size_t pos) noexcept
        {
            return ptr()[pos];
        }

    };

    template <class T, bool reverse = false, bool const_iter = false>
    class ring_buffer_iterator
    {
        T *ptr;
        ring_buffer_index index;
        size_t N;

    public:

        PROVIDE_CONTAINER_TYPES(T);

        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

        ring_buffer_iterator(T *ptr, ring_buffer_index index, size_t N) : ptr{ ptr }, index{ index }, N{ N } {}

        ring_buffer_iterator& operator++()
        {
            if constexpr (!reverse)
                ++index;
            else
                --index;
            return *this;
        }

        ring_buffer_iterator& operator+=(size_t n) { index += n; return *this; }

        ring_buffer_iterator& operator-=(size_t n) { return operator+=(-n); }

        template <bool citer = const_iter, std::enable_if_t<!citer, bool> = true> 
        reference operator*() const
        {
            return ptr[index.as_index(N)];
        }

        template <bool citer = const_iter, std::enable_if_t<citer, bool> = true>
        const_reference operator*() const
        {
            return ptr[index.as_index(N)];
        }

        template <bool citer = const_iter, std::enable_if_t<!citer, bool> = true>
        reference operator[](difference_type n) { return *(*this + n); }

        const_reference operator[](difference_type n) const { return *(*this + n); }

        bool operator!=(ring_buffer_iterator other) const { return index != other.index; }

        bool operator==(ring_buffer_iterator other) const { return index == other.index; }

        friend ring_buffer_iterator operator+(const ring_buffer_iterator& iter, size_t times) { return ring_buffer_iterator{iter.ptr, iter.index + times, iter.N}; }

        friend ring_buffer_iterator operator+(size_t times, const ring_buffer_iterator& iter) { return ring_buffer_iterator{ iter.ptr, iter.index + times, iter.N }; }

        friend ring_buffer_iterator operator-(const ring_buffer_iterator& lhs, size_t times) { return ring_buffer_iterator{lhs.ptr, lhs.index - times, lhs.N}; }

        friend difference_type operator-(const ring_buffer_iterator& lhs, const ring_buffer_iterator& rhs) { return static_cast<difference_type>(lhs.index - rhs.index); }

    };

    template <class T>
    class ring_buffer
    {
        size_t N;
        mutable uninitialized_array<T> raw_buffer;
        ring_buffer_index read_pos, write_pos;

        T& read_ptr() const
        {
            return raw_buffer[read_pos.as_index(N)];
        }

        T& write_ptr() const
        {
            return raw_buffer[write_pos.as_index(N)];
        }

        bool will_remain_linearized(size_t num)
        {
            ring_buffer_index last_elem = write_pos + num - 1;
            return last_elem.as_index(N) >= read_pos.as_index(N);
        }

    public:

        PROVIDE_CONTAINER_TYPES(T);

        using iterator = ring_buffer_iterator<T>;
        using const_iterator = ring_buffer_iterator<T, false, true>;
        using reverse_iterator = ring_buffer_iterator<T, true>;
        using const_reverse_iterator = const ring_buffer_iterator<T, true, true>;

        /*
        contrtuctors and assignment operators
        */

        ring_buffer() : N{0} {}

        ring_buffer(size_t size) : N{ size }, raw_buffer { size } {}

        ring_buffer(ring_buffer&&) noexcept = default;

        ring_buffer(const ring_buffer& other)
        {
            clear();
            N = other.N;
            read_pos = other.read_pos;
            write_pos = other.write_pos;
            raw_buffer.copy(other.raw_buffer, N);
        }

        ring_buffer(std::initializer_list<value_type> init) : ring_buffer(init.size())
        {
            std::uninitialized_copy(init.begin(), init.end(), raw_buffer.ptr());
        }

        template <class InputIterator>
        ring_buffer(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) : ring_buffer(static_cast<size_type>(std::distance(first, last)))
        {
            std::uninitialized_copy(first, last, raw_buffer.ptr());
            write_pos += capacity();
        }

        ring_buffer& operator=(ring_buffer&& other) noexcept
        {
            clear();
            N = other.N;
            read_pos = other.read_pos;
            write_pos = other.write_pos;
            raw_buffer = std::move(other.raw_buffer);
            return *this;

        }

        ring_buffer& operator=(const ring_buffer& other)
        {
            clear();
            N = other.N;
            read_pos = other.read_pos;
            write_pos = other.write_pos;
            raw_buffer.copy(other.raw_buffer, N);
            return *this;
        }

        ~ring_buffer() { clear(); }

        /*
        addition methods
        */

        /*
        add at the back of the buffer , this is usually used rather than add at the front
        */

        void push_back_without_checks(const value_type& value)
        {
            emplace_back_without_checks(value);
        }

        void push_back_without_checks(value_type&& value)
        {
            emplace_back_without_checks(std::move(value));
        }

        bool try_push_back(const value_type& value)
        {
            return try_emplace_back(value);
        }

        bool try_push_back(value_type&& value)
        {
            return try_emplace_back(std::move(value));
        }

        void push_back(const value_type& value)
        {
            emplace_back(value);
        }

        void push_back(value_type&& value)
        {
            emplace_back(std::move(value));
        }

        template <class ...Args>
        void emplace_back_without_checks(Args&& ... args)
        {
            new(&write_ptr()) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            ++write_pos;
        }

        template <class ...Args>
        bool try_emplace_back(Args&& ... args)
        {
            if (full())
                return false;
            emplace_back_without_checks(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            return true;
        }

        template <class ...Args>
        void emplace_back(Args&& ... args)
        {
            if (full())
                pop_front();
            emplace_back_without_checks(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        template <class InputIterator>
        void insert_back(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
        {
            size_t num = static_cast<size_t>(std::distance(first, last));
            if (will_remain_linearized(num))
            {
                std::uninitialized_copy(first, last, &write_ptr());
                write_pos += num;
            }
            else
                std::copy(first, last, std::back_inserter(*this));
        }

        /*
        add at the front of the buffer
        */

        void push_front_without_checks(const value_type& value)
        {
            emplace_front_without_checks(value);
        }

        void push_front_without_checks(value_type&& value)
        {
            emplace_front_without_checks(value);
        }

        bool try_push_front(const value_type& value)
        {
            return try_emplace_front(value);
        }

        bool try_push_front(value_type&& value)
        {
            return try_emplace_front(value);
        }

        void push_front(const value_type& value)
        {
            emplace_front(value);
        }

        void push_front(value_type&& value)
        {
            emplace_front(value);
        }

        template <class ... Args>
        void emplace_front_without_checks(Args&& ... args)
        {
            --read_pos;
            new (&read_ptr()) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        template <class ... Args>
        bool try_emplace_front(Args&& ... args)
        {
            if (full())
                return false;
            emplace_front_without_checks(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        template <class ... Args>
        void emplace_front(Args&& ... args)
        {
            if (full())
                pop_back();
            emplace_front_without_checks(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        template <class InputIterator>
        void insert_front(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
        {
            std::copy(first, last, std::front_inserter(*this));
        }

        /*
        extraction methods
        */

        /*
        extract from the front of the buffer
        used with back insertion to make a FIFO queue
        */

        void pop_front(value_type& value)
        {
            auto& elem = read_ptr();
            value = std::move(elem);
            elem.~T();
            ++read_pos;
        }

        bool try_pop_front(value_type& value)
        {
            if (empty())
                return false;
            pop_front(value);
            return true;
        }

        void pop_front()
        {
            read_ptr().~T();
            ++read_pos;
        }

        bool try_pop_front()
        {
            if (empty())
                return false;
            pop_front();
            return true;
        }

        // dumps num of first elements into dest where dest points to initialized memory
        template <class OutputIterator>
        void pop_front(OutputIterator dest, size_t num)
        {
            move_from_front(dest, num);
            if constexpr (std::is_pod_v<value_type>)
                read_pos += num;
            else
            {
                while (num--)
                    pop_front();
            }
        }

        // dumps num of first elements into dest where dest points to uninitialized memory
        template <class OutputIterator>
        void pop_front(OutputIterator dest, size_t num, no_init_t)
        {
            move_from_front(dest, num, no_init);
            if constexpr (std::is_pod_v<value_type>)
                read_pos += num;
            else
            {
                while (num--)
                    pop_front();
            }
        }

        template <class OutputIterator>
        bool try_pop_front(OutputIterator dest, size_t num)
        {
            if (num > size())
                return false;
            pop_front(dest, num);
            return true;
        }

        template <class OutputIterator>
        bool try_pop_front(OutputIterator dest, size_t num, no_init_t)
        {
            if (num > size())
                return false;
            pop_front(dest, num, no_init);
            return true;
        }


        /*
        extract from the back of the buffer
        used with back insertion to make a LIFO queue
        */

        void pop_back(value_type& value)
        {
            --write_pos;
            auto& elem = write_ptr();
            value = std::move(elem);
            elem.~T();
        }

        bool try_pop_back(value_type& value)
        {
            if (empty())
                return false;
            pop_back(value);
            return true;
        }

        void pop_back()
        {
            --write_pos;
            write_ptr().~T();
        }

        bool try_pop_back()
        {
            if (empty())
                return false;
            pop_back();
            return true;
        }

        template <class OutputIterator>
        void pop_back(OutputIterator dest, size_t num)
        {
            move_from_back(dest, num);
            if constexpr (std::is_pod_v<value_type>)
                write_pos -= num;
            else
            {
                while (num--)
                    pop_back();
            }
        }

        template <class OutputIterator>
        void pop_back(OutputIterator dest, size_t num, no_init_t)
        {
            move_from_back(dest, num, no_init);
            if constexpr (std::is_pod_v<value_type>)
                write_pos -= num;
            else
            {
                while (num--)
                    pop_back();
            }
        }

        template <class OutputIterator>
        bool try_pop_back(OutputIterator dest, size_t num)
        {
            if (size() < num)
                return false;
            pop_back(dest, num);
            return true;
        }

        template <class OutputIterator>
        bool try_pop_back(OutputIterator dest, size_t num, no_init_t)
        {
            if (size() < num)
                return false;
            pop_back(dest, num, no_init);
            return true;
        }

        /*
        accesors
        */

        reference front() { return read_ptr(); }

        reference back()
        {
            auto pos = write_pos;
            --pos;
            return raw_buffer[pos.as_index(N)];
        }

        const_reference front() const { return read_ptr(); }

        const_reference back() const
        {
            auto pos = write_pos;
            --pos;
            return raw_buffer[pos.as_index(N)];
        }

        reference operator[](size_type pos) noexcept
        {
            auto index = read_pos + pos;
            return raw_buffer[index.as_index(N)];
        }

        const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const noexcept
        {
            auto index = read_pos + pos;
            return raw_buffer[index.as_index(N)];
        }

        /*
        ^ ==> read pointer
        > ==> write pointer
        data starts from read pointer to write pointer

        1 - linearized (from empty to full) : there is one array starting from read pointer to write pointer
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | ^ | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | > |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------

        2 - not linearized :
        the first array is from read pointer until the end of the buffer (last index N-1)
        the second array is from the start of the buffer until the write pointer
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | 6 | 7 | 8 | > |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ^ | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |  
        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */

        std::span<value_type> array_one() noexcept
        {
            pointer read_pointer = &read_ptr();
            if (is_linearized()) // or empty
                return std::span<value_type>{read_pointer, read_pointer + size()};
            else
                return std::span<value_type>{read_pointer, raw_buffer.ptr() - read_pointer + size()};
        }

        std::span<const value_type> array_one() const noexcept
        {
            pointer read_pointer = &read_ptr();
            if (is_linearized()) // or empty
                return std::span<const value_type>{read_pointer, read_pointer + size()};
            else
                return std::span<const value_type>{read_pointer, raw_buffer.ptr() - read_pointer + size()};
        }

        std::span<value_type> array_two() noexcept
        {
            if (is_linearized())
                return {};
            else
            {
                return std::span<value_type>{raw_buffer.ptr(), &write_ptr()};
            }
        }

        std::span<const value_type> array_two() const noexcept
        {
            if (is_linearized())
                return {};
            else
            {
                return std::span<const value_type>{raw_buffer.ptr(), &write_ptr()};
            }
        }

        void copy_from_front(value_type& value) const
        {
            value = front();
        }

        value_type copy_from_front() const
        {
            value_type value;
            copy_from_front(value);
            return value;
        }

        void move_from_front(value_type& value)
        {
            value = std::move(front());
        }

        value_type move_from_front()
        {
            value_type value;
            move_from_front(value);
            return value;
        }

        template <class OutputIterator>
        void copy_from_front(OutputIterator dest, size_t num) const
        {
            if (is_linearized())
            {
                pointer begin_iter = &read_ptr();
                pointer end_iter = begin_iter + num;
                std::copy(begin_iter, end_iter, dest);
            }
            else
            {
                auto begin_iter = begin();
                auto end_iter = begin_iter + num;
                std::copy(begin_iter, end_iter, dest);
            }
        }

        template <class OutputIterator>
        void copy_from_front(OutputIterator dest, size_t num, no_init_t) const
        {
            if (is_linearized())
            {
                pointer begin_iter = &read_ptr();
                pointer end_iter = begin_iter + num;
                std::uninitialized_copy(begin_iter, end_iter, dest);
            }
            else
            {
                auto begin_iter = begin();
                auto end_iter = begin_iter + num;
                std::uninitialized_copy(begin_iter, end_iter, dest);
            }
        }

        template <class OutputIterator>
        void move_from_front(OutputIterator dest, size_t num)
        {
            if (is_linearized())
            {
                pointer begin_iter = &read_ptr();
                pointer end_iter = begin_iter + num;
                std::copy(std::make_move_iterator(begin_iter), std::make_move_iterator(end_iter), dest);
            }
            else
            {
                auto begin_iter = begin();
                auto end_iter = begin_iter + num;
                std::copy(std::make_move_iterator(begin_iter), std::make_move_iterator(end_iter), dest);
            }
        }

        template <class OutputIterator>
        void move_from_front(OutputIterator dest, size_t num, no_init_t)
        {
            if (is_linearized())
            {
                pointer begin_iter = &read_ptr();
                pointer end_iter = begin_iter + num;
                std::uninitialized_move(begin_iter, end_iter, dest);
            }
            else
            {
                auto begin_iter = begin();
                auto end_iter = begin_iter + num;
                std::uninitialized_move(begin_iter, end_iter, dest);
            }
        }

        void copy_from_back(value_type& value) const
        {
            value = back();
        }

        value_type copy_from_back() const
        {
            value_type value;
            copy_from_back(value);
            return value;
        }

        void move_from_back(value_type& value)
        {
            value = std::move(back());
        }

        value_type move_from_back()
        {
            value_type value;
            move_from_back(value);
            return value;
        }

        template <class OutputIterator>
        void copy_from_back(OutputIterator dest, size_t num) const
        {
            if (is_linearized())
            {
                pointer end_iter = &write_ptr();
                pointer first = end_iter - num;
                std::copy(first, end_iter, dest);
            }
            else
            {
                auto end_iter = end();
                auto first = end_iter - num;
                std::copy(first, end_iter, dest);
            }
        }

        template <class OutputIterator>
        void copy_from_back(OutputIterator dest, size_t num, no_init_t) const
        {
            if (is_linearized())
            {
                pointer end_iter = &write_ptr();
                pointer first = end_iter - num;
                std::uninitialized_copy(first, end_iter, dest);
            }
            else
            {
                auto end_iter = end();
                auto first = end_iter - num;
                std::uninitialized_copy(first, end_iter, dest);
            }
        }

        template <class OutputIterator>
        void move_from_back(OutputIterator dest, size_t num)
        {
            if (is_linearized())
            {
                pointer end_iter = &write_ptr();
                pointer first = end_iter - num;
                std::copy(std::make_move_iterator(first), std::make_move_iterator(end_iter), dest);
            }
            else
            {
                auto end_iter = end();
                auto first = end_iter - num;
                std::copy(std::make_move_iterator(first), std::make_move_iterator(end_iter), dest);
            }
        }

        template <class OutputIterator>
        void move_from_back(OutputIterator dest, size_t num, no_init_t)
        {
            if (is_linearized())
            {
                pointer end_iter = &write_ptr();
                pointer first = end_iter - num;
                std::uninitialized_move(first, end_iter, dest);
            }
            else
            {
                auto end_iter = end();
                auto first = end_iter - num;
                std::uninitialized_move(first, end_iter, dest);
            }
        }

        /*
        range methods
        */

        iterator begin() noexcept { return iterator{raw_buffer.ptr(), read_pos, N}; }

        iterator end() noexcept { return iterator{raw_buffer.ptr(), write_pos, N}; }

        const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return const_iterator{raw_buffer.ptr(), read_pos, N}; }

        const_iterator end() const noexcept { return const_iterator{raw_buffer.ptr(), write_pos, N}; }

        const_iterator cbegin() const noexcept { return begin(); }

        const_iterator cend() const noexcept { return end(); }

        reverse_iterator rbegin() noexcept { return reverse_iterator{ raw_buffer.ptr(), write_pos - 1, N }; }

        reverse_iterator rend() noexcept { return reverse_iterator{ raw_buffer.ptr(), read_pos - 1, N }; }

        const_reverse_iterator rbegin() const noexcept { return const_reverse_iterator{ raw_buffer.ptr(), write_pos - 1, N }; }

        const_reverse_iterator rend() const noexcept { return const_reverse_iterator{ raw_buffer.ptr(), read_pos - 1, N }; }

        const_reverse_iterator crbegin() const noexcept { return rbegin(); }

        const_reverse_iterator crend() const noexcept { return rend(); }


        /*
        eraser, linearization, resize and some info
        */

        void clear()
        {
            if constexpr (std::is_pod_v<value_type>)
            {
                read_pos.reset();
                write_pos.reset();
            }
            else
            {
                while (!empty())
                    pop_front();
            }
        }

        pointer linearize()
        {
            ring_buffer rbf(N);
            auto first_array = array_one();
            rbf.insert_back(std::make_move_iterator(first_array.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(first_array.end()));
            auto second_array = array_two();
            rbf.insert_back(std::make_move_iterator(second_array.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(second_array.end()));
            this->operator=(std::move(rbf));
            return raw_buffer.ptr();
        }

        template <class OutputIterator>
        void linearize(OutputIterator dest) const
        {
            auto first_array = array_one();
            std::copy(first_array.begin(), first_array.end(), dest);
            auto second_array = array_two();
            std::copy(second_array.begin(), second_array.end(), dest + first_array.size());
        }

        void set_capacity(size_type Num)
        {
            clear();
            N = Num;
            raw_buffer.resize(Num);
        }

        size_t capacity() const noexcept { return N; }

        size_t size() const noexcept { return write_pos - read_pos; }

        size_t available_size() const noexcept { return capacity() - size(); }

        size_t reserve() const noexcept { return available_size(); }

        bool full() const noexcept { return size() == capacity(); }

        bool empty() const noexcept { return !size(); }

        bool is_linearized() const noexcept 
        {
            ring_buffer_index last_pos = write_pos - 1;
            return last_pos.as_index(N) >= read_pos.as_index(N);
        }

        /*
        aliases to use the ring buffer as FIFO
        */

        template <class ...Args>
        void emplace(Args&& ... args)
        {
            emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        void push(const value_type& value)
        {
            push_back(value);
        }

        void push(value_type&& value)
        {
            push_back(std::move(value));
        }

        template <class InputIterator>
        void insert(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
        {
            insert_back(first, last);
        }

        void pop(value_type& value)
        {
            pop_front(value);
        }

        bool try_pop(value_type& value)
        {
            return try_pop_front(value);
        }

        void pop()
        {
            pop_front();
        }

        bool try_pop()
        {
            return try_pop_front();
        }

        template <class OutputIt>
        void pop(OutputIt dest, size_t num)
        {
            pop_front(dest, num);
        }

        template <class OutputIt>
        void pop(OutputIt dest, size_t num, no_init_t)
        {
            pop_front(dest, num, no_init);
        }

        template <class OutputIt>
        bool try_pop(OutputIt dest, size_t num)
        {
            return try_pop_front(dest, num);
        }

        template <class OutputIt>
        bool try_pop(OutputIt dest, size_t num, no_init_t)
        {
            return try_pop_front(dest, num, no_init);
        }

    };
```

The `span.h` header can be found [here](https://github.com/some-coder366/ring-buffer/blob/master/span.h).

I found it somewhere on the internet since some months ago, but I can't recall where did I get it from and as said in the title it's an implementation for the new C++ 20 `span` which represents a view for a range of contiguous memory, like `string_view`, but it enables to non `const` access the values if it isn't `const`.

I want to know:

- Does the implementation misuse the concept of ring buffer?
- Do the iterators satisfy the C++ concept of iterators?
- Is there any drawbacks of using the indexes as counters and obtaining the real indexes with modulus especially for bigger values?

Comment: The class `SomeClass` makes this question off-topic because it seems to be hypothetical. Is the class necessary to the question, and if it is could you better define it?

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying but I wrote it as an example to illustrate why I favored overwriting by destructing and constructing rather than by assigning . if you see it's better to reassign then I'll be pleased to hear your opinion

Comment: The name of the class and possibly the usage makes it hypothetical. We review code and suggest how it can be improved. Reassigning versus destruction/construction might be considered opinion based and off-topic.

Comment: I don't know why it's off-topic . the boost's website claims that reassigning is more efficient

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: @dev65 ^ Particularly check https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652

Comment: but the page says : 'If your question was asking for a review of pseudocode, then we need you to post an implementation in a real programming language' and I don't ask about reassigning vs destruct/construct generally as each has its uses . instead I ask if the method I'm using in the code for ring buffer is better than reassigning

Comment: Can you also add some test cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching I found that my ring buffer is broken if its capacity isn't power of 2, because once the counter reaches its maximum (on 64-bit : 2^64 - 1) it will begin from zero the next increment so if the modulus of the counter by n isn't n-1 when it reaches the maximum unsigned integer of the architecture then the counter will misbehave because at the next step the remainder (index) will be 0 while the previous remainder (index) isn't n - 1

this illustrates the problem :

```
constexpr uint64_t rem1 = std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() % 13;
cout << "rem1 = " << rem1 << endl; // rem1 = 2
constexpr uint64_t rem2 = (std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() + 1) % 13; // std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() + 1 = 0
cout << "rem2 = " << rem2 << endl; // rem2 = 0 not 3 !
```

but for number n equals power of two the remainder will be n -1 at maximum value so no problem here

Answer (score 0):

As long as the index values are not insanely high, you could use recursion and still have odd size arrays.

```
size_t as_index(size_t N, size_t index)
{
    if (pos < N)
        return pos;
    return as_index(N, pos - N);
}
```

Loved the code by the way. The only real change I did is remove `ring_buffer_index` (since all you need is `as_index`) and `uninitialized_array` (as I could swap it with a `std::span` and wanted to use fixed arrays).